# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO WITH multiple SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-insert

I'm looking for an SQL Statement to achieve the following:

I have a table that is like {id**a** | id**b** | count | direct}
I want to insert rows into the table taking the ids **a** and **b** from another table, count and direct are given values. I tried something like this:

***Not Working:***

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl (ida, idb, count, direct)  
SELECT id FROM other_tbl WHERE word ='test'  
UNION  
SELECT id FROM other_tbl WHERE word ='tost' 23, 5;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `word ='tost' 23, 5` valid grammar in pssql?

Comment: Your insert columns must be match with select columns.
In this sample u are trying to insert four columns with selecting one columns.

Comment: probably not, i tried to get this query working by try and error and this is where i decided to get help

Comment: @MatthiasSchroer . . . Sample data and desired results are usually a big help in conveying meaning.

Comment: @KadirÇetintaş i have some trouble getting to values from the same other_tbl with different wheres, is there a way to do this (and combine them with two given values)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl (ida, idb, count, direct) 
    SELECT o1.id, o2.id, 23, 5
    FROM other_tbl o1 JOIN
         other_tbl o2
         ON o1.word = 'test' AND o2.word = 'tost';
```

Comment: yeah this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks!